# Splitting text to words with R and cSplit()

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I'm trying to split a series of sentences into separate words, that is, to tokenize the text.

I have found an R package `splitstackshape` that is able to do what I want, well almost... it truncates the output to the first and last 5 rows.

Anyway, this is what I need to do:

```
id text
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Donec euismod enim quis 
4 nunc fringilla sodales
5 Etiam tempor ligula vitae 
6 pellentesque dictum
7 Quisque non justo scelerisque 
8 est facilisis congue quis vel
9 Phasellus ex lorem
10 eleifend at magna vel
11 egestas eleifend massa
```

Output:

```
id word
1 Lorem
1 ipsum
1 dolor
1 sit
1 amet
2 consectetur
2 adipiscing
...
```

That is, I need words in separate rows, but with alongside the ID of the sentence it belongs to.

I was trying `cSplit(data, "text", " ", "long")`, but it truncates..

---

**Update. FYI, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694457/r-joining-rows-to-single-column-based-on-id/) is how to do the reverse**

Comment: what do you mean by 'it truncates' ? It does exactly the job you want, remind that it's a data.table as output and you can convert it to data.frame if needed.

Comment: That's just the display output of "data.table".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cSplit` function returns a `data.table`.

What you are describing is the default print behavior for `data.table`s. To see this in action, try the following:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(airquality)
print(as.data.table(airquality))

print(as.data.table(airquality), nrows = Inf)
```

Thus, to get the full table displayed, you can try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
print(cSplit(data, "text", " ", "long"), nrows = Inf)
```

Comment: ...and now when I understand that the output was a data.table, I can easily convert it back to a data.frame.