# R: Joining rows to single column based on ID

Tags: r

A while ago I asked for help on how to do the reverse of what I want to do now, this discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624120/splitting-text-to-words-with-r-and-csplit). Anyway, I now need to join my data back into the format it once was. That is, to join the separate rows (each containing a word), into one sentence per ID. For example:

Input:

```
id word
1 Lorem
1 ipsum
1 dolor
1 sit
1 amet
2 consectetur
2 adipiscing
2 elit
3 Donec
...
```

Output:

```
id text
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Donec euismod enim quis 
4 nunc fringilla sodales
5 Etiam tempor ligula vitae 
6 pellentesque dictum
```

At first, I tried to do this with the `reshape` package and its `melt()` and `cast()` functions. I also tried the `tidyr` package. However, these functions rely on a variable name column specifying the column name for each of the new columns. Not exactly my case (and each sentence can be of different length).

How can I do this task in `R`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregating by unique identifier and concatenating related values into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596515/aggregating-by-unique-identifier-and-concatenating-related-values-into-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we `paste` the 'word' together.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(text= paste(word, collapse=' ')), by = id]
#   id                        text
#1:  1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
#2:  2 consectetur adipiscing elit
#3:  3                       Donec
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can similarly group by 'id' and `paste` the 'word' column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(text= paste(word, collapse=' '))
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
aggregate(word~id, df1, FUN = paste, collapse=' ')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L),
word = c("Lorem", 
"ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", 
"elit", "Donec")), .Names = c("id", "word"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew ther had to be an easy way to do this. 
And WOW, that was a fast reply!